# How to configure warm-up of web-service application within Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, web-services, warm-up

On IIS I can configure my web-service with Application Initialization, AlwaysRunning and Preload enabled to make sure the first request is fast enough. Now I am trying to create a similar web-service within Microsoft Azure. However, the first request is exteremely slow. I tried to speed it up using "Always on", but this doesn't work. What configuration is needed to make sure the warm-up works correctly in Azure?

I would like to make Azure react the same way as IIS when restarting the application or refreshing the web.config. Besides the "Always on" functionality, I can't find the settings that are needed to do this. I have searched on other pages, but most solutions are about the warm-up of a website page. Is there a (simple) configuration to use for the warm-up of a web-service within an Azure app service?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Preload?

When you create the Web Service Application in azure...
Under Settings, Configuration, Path Mappings..

[image]

Comment: I did not think to check Path Mappings...  Thanks!

Comment: this didn't work for me